# nginx file configuration with static folder, in Flask+Gunicorn+Nginx application

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have a Flask+Gunicorn+Nginx app, this is the settings for the sites-available file inside etc/nginx.

My problem is that the application does not load the images and the css styles, but the Flask logical theme, routes, login and others work.

The problem is with my static folder.

This is the configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name dominio.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominio.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominio.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/suppliers.sock;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/soporte/portal_providers/app_Portal;
        autoindex off;
    }
}

server {
    if ($host = dominio.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name dominio.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**Archive blueprint Flask:**

```
auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__,template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')
```

**Link in the html with the image:**

```
{% block logo %}
<img src="images/Logo--definitivo.jpg" class="menu-logo py-0 " style="z-index: auto">
{% endblock %}
```

project structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bydf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `root` instead of `alias`. The (working, deployed) nginx config for an app I'm working on does

```
location /static/ {
    root /home/pi/app;
    autoindex off;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added what you tell me, but I still have the same problem.
Update the initial comment, with the url of the image, and the configuration file so that you can see it please, which one was updated.

Comment: If you comment out the location block for `/static/` and static files are suddenly visible, it's likely a permission issue.

Comment: Hello, thanks, indeed when you remove the static route, it already loads the styles. Check permissions of the entire folder and the user has full permissions, do you know what other permissions can be?

Comment: They were indeed permissions, with the user www-data in the site folder. Thank you very much for your help Dave W